# Group Products by Brand then by Category - linq

Tags: c#, linq

There is three table:

```
Brand                               Category
-----------------------          --------------------------------
BrandID     BrandName             CategoryID        CategoryName
-----------------------          --------------------------------
1           Brand1                    1             cat1
2           Brand2                    2             cat2

Product
------------------------------------------------------------
ProductID       BrandID      CategoryID    ProductName
------------------------------------------------------------   
1                 1             1          Product1
2                 1             1          Product2
3                 1             2          Product3
4                 2             1          Product4
```

I want to write Llinq query to get output like below:

```
Brand1
|__ cat1
|   |__ Product1
|   |__ Product2
|
|__ Cat2
|   |__ Product3
|
|__ Brand2
|__ cat1
|   |__ Product4
```

I Wrote this query to get Product group by Category:

```
    var query2 = db.Brands
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.BrandID, x.BrandName })
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.Key.BrandID,
                        x.Key.BrandName,
                        ProductsNames = db.Products
                                            .Where(p => p.BrandID == x.Key.BrandID)
                                            .Select(p => p.ProductName).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

How can Group Products by Brand then by Category?

Comment: You are using the table db.Brands which does not have Category.  Instead use the table db.Products.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps

```
//Step 1 - Join 3 lists
var query = (from p in products
                join b in brands on p.BrandId equals b.Id
                join c in categories on p.CategoryId equals c.Id
                select new
                {
                    b.BrandName,
                    c.CategoryName,
                    p.ProductName
                }).ToList();

//Step 2 - query required results
var results = query
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.BrandName, x.CategoryName })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Brand = x.Key.BrandName,
                    Category = x.Key.CategoryName,
                    Product = x.Select(y=>y.ProductName).ToList()
                });

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results));
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {
        "Brand": "Brand1",
        "Category": "cat1",
        "Product": [
            "Product1",
            "Product2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Brand1",
        "Category": "cat2",
        "Product": [
            "Product3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Brand": "Brand2",
        "Category": "cat1",
        "Product": [
            "Product4"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>{
            new Product { ProductID = 1, BrandID = 1, CategoryID = 1, ProductName = "Product1" },
            new Product { ProductID = 2, BrandID = 1, CategoryID = 1, ProductName = "Product2" },
            new Product { ProductID = 3, BrandID = 1, CategoryID = 2, ProductName = "Product3" },
            new Product { ProductID = 4, BrandID = 2, CategoryID = 1, ProductName = "Product4" }
        };
        var groupedByBrand = 
            products
                .GroupBy(p => p.BrandID)
                .Select(g => g.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryID));
        foreach (var groupByBrand in groupedByBrand)
            foreach (var groupByCategory in groupByBrand)
                foreach (var product in groupByCategory)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{product.BrandID} - {product.ProductName}");
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; internal set; }
    public int BrandID { get; internal set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; internal set; }
    public string ProductName { get; internal set; }
}
```

I grouped by BrandId and then inside this group grouped by categoryId.

If it is just about the grouping you can use the BrandID and CategoryID and don't even need to join the tables. if you want to sort by name then of course you need to join.

Maybe you wanted to do some sorting on top of / instead of grouping?

Comment: Yes, I need name of brand and category to showing to user.

Answer (score 0):

In one step , more compact manner

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; internal set; }
        public string ProductName { get; internal set; }
        public Brand brand { get; set; }
        public Category cat { get; set; }
        public Product()
        {
            brand = new Brand();
            cat = new Category();
        }
    }

    public class Brand
    {
        public int BrandID { get; internal set; }
        public string BrandName { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; internal set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; internal set; }
    }

private void a1()
{
    var products = new List<Product>{
    new Product { ProductID = 1,
                                brand =new Brand { BrandID = 1, BrandName = "Brand1" },
                                cat = new Category { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "cat1" },
                                ProductName = "Product1" },
    new Product { ProductID = 2,
                                brand =new Brand { BrandID = 1, BrandName = "Brand1" },
                                cat = new Category { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "cat1" },
                                ProductName = "Product2" },
    new Product { ProductID = 3,
                                brand =new Brand { BrandID = 1, BrandName = "Brand1" },
                                cat = new Category { CategoryID = 2, CategoryName = "cat2" },
                                ProductName = "Product3" },
    new Product { ProductID = 4,
                                brand =new Brand { BrandID = 2, BrandName = "Brand2" },
                                cat = new Category { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "cat1" },
                                ProductName = "Product4" }
    };

    var g1 = products.GroupBy(p => new { p.brand, p.cat, p })
                        .Select(y => new 
                        {
                            k1 = y.Key.brand.BrandName,
                            k2 = y.Key.cat.CategoryName,
                            k3 = y.Key.p.ProductName
                        }       
                        );
}

// Result/Output as below
{ k1 = "Brand1", k2 = "cat1", k3 = "Product1" }
{ k1 = "Brand1", k2 = "cat1", k3 = "Product2" }
{ k1 = "Brand1", k2 = "cat2", k3 = "Product3" }
{ k1 = "Brand2", k2 = "cat1", k3 = "Product4" }
```